# Opencart bitnami docker - How to mount host directories as data volumes in proper way

Tags: php, docker, opencart, bitnami

I use [bitnami docker](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-mariadb) for running my Opencart application and I have a question how should I describe data volumes in my docker-compose file in a proper way?

I mean - I build an a payment extension, so I have standard structured folders like admin/controller/extension/payment/, catalog/, system/ etc. and this is how I set volumes in docker-compose:

```
  volumes:
-./my_extension/admin/controller/extension/payment/my_extension.php:/opt/bitnami/opencart/admin/controller/extension/payment/my_extension.php
-./my_extension/admin/language/en-gb/extension/payment/my_extension.php:/opt/bitnami/opencart/admin/language/en-gb/extension/payment/my_extension.php
```

I pass every file from my extension as next volume, I know it's not correct but I don't know how should I do this

Comment: Bitnami engineer here. If the application requires the different files to be placed in different folders, that's the way to follow. I don't know if you can simply copy a folder to a specific directory w/o the need of copying the files to different places. That's something you will need to check in the app's documentation or forums. Thanks

Comment: @JotaMartos Ok, I understand, thank you for your answer!